# Wo geht's hier zum Theater?

Tags: phrase, grammaticality

I don't quite understand the logic/grammar behind the phrase *wo geht's hier*... For example,

> „Wo gehts hier zum Theater?“ - „Da müssen Sie immer geradeaus gehen!“

What does the contracted *'es'* in *geht'**s*** refer to?

For some reason, it also seems to me that *wo* and *gehen* don't really go well together. "***Wo*** steht etwas?" makes sense to me but I'm not so sure about "***wo*** geht etwas?"

I also thought "*wie*" would be more logical, like in the English "*How do I get to...?*", so I would be more likely to say something like "***Wie*** geht man zum Theater?". But I don't know if it's idiomatic in German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '*es*' does not refer to anything in this context. It is used simply as a formality within the sentence structure, but does not have a meaning.

I don't know how good your German is, but [this page](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html) explains the different contexts of '*es*' very well.

And in terms of "*wie*" and "*wo*", as a native German I would not consider one right or wrong. Both are used and accepted. I couldn't explain you grammatically where the differences lie. I would just recommend you using what you feel comfortable with. "*Wie gehts zum Theater?*" and "*Wo gehts zum Theater?*" mean the same. I personally would use *wie*, but I think the differences lie within different regions, not necessarily grammar.

Hope this helped.

Comment: *"Wo geht hier zum Theater?"* -  ist nicht korrektes Deutsch. und *"How do i get to"* würde ich eher mit *"Wie komme ich zu / nach"* übersetzen. (als kleine Verbesserungsanregungen). Nebenbei: welches von den vielen "es" ist jetzt das hier?

Comment: Thanks for the link explaining "es". @Vogel612 Why do you say "Wie gehts zu...?" and "Wie komme ich zu...?" and NOT "Wie kommts zu...?" or "Wie gehe ich zu...?". In other words, why does "gehen" work in the impersonal construction but not in the personal one?

Comment: @stillenat wieso sollte es nicht funktionieren?? Die Bedeutung ändert sich aber. *"Wie kommt es zu ...?"* wäre *"How does ... happen?"*, und wegen *"Wie gehe ich zu ...?"* habe ich leider keine wirkliche Erklärung. Ich weiß, dass es falsch ist, aber nicht warum. Vielleicht willst du diesbezüglich eine neue Frage stellen

Comment: Für mich klingt *"Wie geht's zum Theater?"* zwar nicht wirklich falsch, aber doch reichlich ungewöhnlich und eher auf spezielle Umstände anwendbar. Für mich wären die möglichen Fragen *"**Wo geht's** zum Theater?"* oder aber *"**Wie komme ich** zum Theater?"* - mit der zweiten Formulierung läuft man freilich Gefahr, falls man an einen Scherzkeks geraten ist, als Antwort *"viel üben"* zu hören